# Laravel:Integrity constraint violation error while creating factory

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have a model called Student & created a factory for the same but when try to execute the factory from the tinker shell it gives me this error,

> lluminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]:
> Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'institute_id' cannot be
> null (SQL: insert into `students` (`institute_id`, `user_id`,
> `first_name`, `last_name`, `father_name`, `father_contact`,
> `mother_name`, `mother_contact`, `address`, `dob`, `contact_no`,
> `standard`, `last_qualification`, `last_school_name`,
> `last_coaching_name`, `academic_year`, `rank_holder`, `batch_id`,
> `branch_id`, `gender`, `total_fees`) values (?, 50, Henriette,
> Watsica, Lucious, 8024956975, Lolita, 9236983309, 135 Lynch Rapid Port
> Retha, TX 10297, 2003-04-06, 6895209267, 1, 9th, Upton, Rath and
> Turcotte, Lubowitz, Reynolds and Emmerich, 2020-2021, ?, 1, 1, male,
> 20000))'

Here is my Studentfactory,

```
<?php

/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */

use App\Student;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(Student::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    $inst_id = factory(App\Institute::class)->create()->id;
    // dd($inst_id); This prints the id on the shell
    return [
        'institute_id' => $inst_id,
        'user_id' => factory(App\User::class),
        'first_name' => $faker->firstName,
        'last_name' => $faker->lastName,
        'father_name' => $faker->firstNameMale,
        'father_contact' => rand(1111111111, 9999999999),
        'mother_name' => $faker->firstNameFemale,
        'mother_contact' => rand(1111111111, 9999999999),
        'address' => $faker->address,
        'dob' => $faker->date(),
        'contact_no' => rand(1111111111, 9999999999),
        'standard' => 1,
        'last_qualification' => '9th',
        'last_school_name'  => $faker->company,
        'last_coaching_name' => $faker->company,
        'academic_year' => '2020-2021',
        'rank_holder' => null,
        'batch_id' => 1,
        'branch_id' => 1,
        'gender' => 'male',
        'total_fees' => '20000',

    ];
});
```

Student Schema,

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

class Students extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('institute_id');
            $table->string('user_id');
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('father_name');
            $table->string('father_contact')->nullable();
            $table->string('mother_name');
            $table->string('mother_contact')->nullable();
            $table->text('address');
            $table->date('dob');
            $table->string('contact_no');
            $table->string('standard');
            $table->string('last_qualification');
            $table->string('last_school_name');
            $table->string('last_coaching_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('total_fees')->nullable();
            $table->string('academic_year')->nullable();
            $table->string('rank_holder')->nullable();
            $table->string('batch_id');
            $table->string('branch_id');
            $table->string('gender');
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->string('status')->default(Config::get('constants.student_active', 1));
            $table->text('extra_data')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('students');
    }
}
```

As you can see in my code I try to dump the generated Id & it gives me proper Id but it fails to execute the SQL.Am I doing anything wrong here?Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Update your question and include your schema design

Comment: Hey @BasheerKharoti, I have updated my question as you have asked.

Comment: Are you sure it's printing the `institute_id`? Because this factory is working for me perfectly

Comment: @BasheerKharoti Yes it's dumping the institute_id on the console & I am also can't figure it out that if its prints the id then why not taking it in the SQL execution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the anwser if anyone looking in the future.So after lot of debugging I finally solved my own problem.The problem was in the Student(Model).In the model there is mutator for institute_id like this,

```
public function setInstituteIdAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['institute_id'] = request()->input('institute_id');
    }
```

Here you can see I handle the insitute_id quite differently.As factory usses Model to create new database records so whenever i passed the institute_id in factory then the Model makes it NULL as it cannot find it in the request object So I changed my code to this & voila everything starts working.

```
public function setInstituteIdAttribute($value)
 {
        $this->attributes['institute_id'] = !empty(request()->input('institute_id')) ? request()->input('institute_id') : $value;
    }
```